# Google Sheet Index?

Tags: arrays, list, indexing, google-sheets, dropdown

I have a dropdown list on Google Sheets, column A. Depending on what option is selected, I need column B to show the associated value. I tried using the `INDEX` functions but I am not sure I get it on how to use it, as to me is the same as using "=" to a specific cell. Basically I need to associate values:

```
COLUMNS:

  A          B
ORANGES = VERY GOOD
APPLES  = yuck!
BANANAS = NICE!
```

So if on column A, "APPLES" was selected from the dropdown list, the column B should show the associated value for that option ("yuck!").

Comment: the dropdown list is a list from a range on plain text, the list contents is located on a different tab, but the data validation dropdown list is on each cell on a single column, the corresponding value should appear next to the selected value, so lets say;

 on cell A1, i choose "ORANGES" from the dropdown list
cell B1 should reflect the corresponding assigned value "very good"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually found a solution, using Nested IF'S,

```
      =IF(A1="ORANGES","VERY GOOD",IF(A1="APPLES","YUCK!",IF(A1="BANANAS","NICE!")))
```

add as many if statements as needed